# Issues with fakerjs generating decmial bumber by template

Tags: javascript, faker

I have an issues with `faker.fake()` generating decimal value from template

```
const a = faker.finance.amount(9, 100, 4); // all good
const b = faker.fake('{{finance.amount(9, 100, 4)}}'); // always NaN
```

However things like

```
const c = faker.fake('{{random.number}}') // all good
```

works just fine ^.

I am using `fakerjs` `4.1.0`

Thoughts?

Comment: I was stepping through faker.js with a debugger, and this seems like it's probably a bug in faker.js, so better to call faker.finance.amount directly for now.

Comment: (namely in faker.js there is a line **result = fn.call(this, params);** which maybe should be **result = fn.apply(this, params);** because otherwise it can never pass more than one argument, as you want to do here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug inside faker.js, so you will have to use finance.amount directly and not faker.fake.

---

If you read the faker.js source, you can see it uses **call**:

```
this.fake = function fake (str) {
    ...
    result = fn.call(this, params);
    ...
}
```

If you call faker.fake('{{finance.amount(9, 100, 4)}}'); it will internally try to call faker.finance.amount("9, 100, 4"); which results in NaN.

There seems to be no way to pass three arguments to finance.amount using faker.fake.